# Scheme: How to find a position of a char in a string

Tags: string, list, position, scheme, racket

I am trying to find the index of a string where it is equal to a certain character, but I can seem to figure it out. 
This is what I got so far, but its not working...

```
(define getPos 
  (lambda ()
    (define s (apply string-append myList))
    (getPosition pos (string->list s))))

(define getPosition 
  (lambda (position s)
    (if (and (< position (length s)) (equal? (car s) #\space)) 
        ((set! pos (+ pos 1)) (getPosition (cdr s) pos));increment the positon and continue the loop
        pos)));else

(define length
  (lambda (s);the value s must be coverted to a string->list when passed in
    (cond
      ((null? s) 0)
      (else (+ 1 (length (cdr s)))))))
```

Comment: When you have double set of parentheses it means you are going to call the result of the expression as a procedure.. Eg. `((get-function) 5 6)` BUT `set!` is known to evaluate to an unknown value so it won't become a valid procedure object. For blocks you use `(begin expression ...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple: we have to test each char in the list until either we run out of elements or we find the first occurrence of the char, keeping track of which position we're in.

Your proposed solution looks weird, in Scheme we try to avoid `set!` and other operations that mutate data - the way to go, is by using recursion to traverse the list of chars. Something like this is preferred:

```
(define (getPosition char-list char pos)
  (cond ((null? char-list) #f)              ; list was empty
        ((char=? char (car char-list)) pos) ; we found it!
        (else (getPosition (cdr char-list) char (add1 pos))))) ; char was not found
```

For 0-based indexes use it like this, converting the string to a list of chars and initializing the position in `0`:

```
(getPosition (string->list "abcde") #\e 0)
=> 4
```

Of course, we can do better by using existing procedures - here's a more idiomatic solution:

```
(require srfi/1) ; required for using the `list-index` procedure

(define (getPosition string char)
  (list-index (curry char=? char) 
              (string->list string)))

(getPosition "abcde" #\e)
=> 4
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but in the end I actually figured it out myself ^_^

Comment: @user2403836 ok, but I _do_ hope that you stop using `set!` for implementing a loop, that's the wrong way to traverse a list in Scheme ;)

Comment: so lets say if i want to set x to 2 in a functions would i do (define x 2)?

Comment: @user2403836 yes, that's one way to assign a value to a variable. Also you can use `let` or `let*`. But the point is - when programming in Scheme, after you assign an initial value to a variable, you don't _modify_ it afterwards - if the value must change, then the modification is passed as a parameter to a function call, but it should not be modified in-place using `set!`. Granted, there are valid uses for `set!`, but looping is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `for`:

```
#lang racket

(define (find-char c s)
  (for/first ([x s]              ; for each character in the string c
              [i (in-naturals)]  ; counts 0, 1, 2, ...
              #:when (char=? c x))
    i))

(find-char #\o "hello world")
(find-char #\x "hello world")
```

Output:

```
4
#f
```